# Using "var this" inside remote CFC methods

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

I've inherited a project where there are a number of remote CFC's opened up for some Ajax requests and **inside** most methods in the CFC have the following:

`<cfset var this.response = true />`

Now I've never seen the `var` and `this` scope used together like this so I'm really not sure what to make of it so I guess my questions is:

**Are there any issues with how this was coded? If so, are they major enough that I should put in
the effort to update all the CFC's to something like** `<cfset var
req.response = true />`**?**

Here is a quick example of what I'm seeing:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="check_foo" access="remote" returnformat="plain">

        <cfargument
          name     = "isfoo"
          type     = "string"
          required = "false"
          default  = "nope"
          hint     = "I check the string for foo"
          />

        <cfscript>

          /*setup new response*/
          var this.response = false;

          /*check for foo*/
          if( !findnocase( "foo", arguments.isfoo ) ) {

            /*no foo!*/
            this.response = false;

          }

          return this.response;

        </cfscript>

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

.

---

### Updates:

1. Based on the feedback/answers below I've replace all instances of `var this`. Thanks again to everyone that helped out!

.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `var this` is the same as using `this`.

Dumping the `local` scope will include local variables as well as the `Arguments` and `This` scopes. (Can't find this documented; but I get this result in a bare cfc, and you got it in your screenshots.)

Because your function is `access="remote"` you'll be getting a new instance of the cfc on every call, and therefore a bare `This` scope. So those are "safe", but still a bad idea.

If there is any use of `var this` in non-remote functions then you will be getting undesired persistence and may suffer race conditions that result is invalid data.

Relevant CF documentation:

"[Methods that are executed remotely through Flash Remoting and web services always create a new instance of the CFC before executing the method.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=buildingComponents_15.html)"

"[Variable values in the This scope last as long as the CFC instance exists and, therefore, can persist between calls to methods of a CFC instance.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e15)"

Comment: Thanks @nosilleg, very helpful. To be safe, I went through the non-remote CFC's and didn't see any instance of `var this` being used.

Answer (score 4):

**update**:  upon checking your dump, the "this" in `var this` is still this `this` scope, not local.this.

It is setting the response to the `this` scope, and it works in this case because because the CFC is instantiated every time it's being invoked remotely.  However, it'd be best to rename `this` into something else to ensure thread-safety in case the method is invoked by other CFC as public method.

Comment: Thanks @Henry, that helps. [Here are the dumps](http://imgur.com/3IToy) on both the `this` and `local` scopes... I don't see any cause for alarm but would you still recommend renaming `var this`?

Comment: yes, rename `var this.response` to `var response`, just in case.

Comment: @Henry It appears people prefer your answer despite the first two sentences being wrong. (At least according to my investigations).  Are you happy to amend your answer, or for me to, so that someone who just looks at your answer isn't misguided? (Or point out my misunderstanding if that's the case.)